# SCSS style to implement a small dot

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I want to have a dot of green color in my view.
I want to set up a dot on the ion2-calender component.What i have tried is to write a scss is  to.The green color is comming but the digit is getting downwards.Please help me so that digit 14 does not go down,[image]

```
  button.days-btn.dot:before{

  content: '\25CF';
  font-size:25px;
  color:green;


  }
```

Comment: If you can create a reproducible demo of this will be able to help better..

Comment: Apply `position:absolute` to the `dot:before` and `position:relative` to the parent of the dot. You may control the position of the dot once the position is absolute using `top` or `left`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` to handle the dot position within the box.

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.container span {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

div.container span.green-dot:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
  top: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span class="green-dot">3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @midhunsivarajan You can accept my answer if this helped :)